# deploy SQL Server Express LocalDB database app with "clr enabled"

Tags: .net, sql-server, clr, sqlclr, localdb

Cross posted on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/643eb7b1-b2a4-4bc9-82ca-6e97dba1df5d/localdb-deployment-how-to-enable-clr-on-target-machines?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

My app uses the group_concat custom functions on [codeplex](https://groupconcat.codeplex.com/)

I am getting the following error when starting up the app on target machine.

`Execution of user code in the .NET framework is disabled. Enable clr enabled configuration option.`

Assuming localdb is installed on target machine, what can I do to enable clr along with install? On my machine, i just opened SSMS and executed the script there.

`sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO`

However, SSMS will not be installed on most clients and I am not sure how to make it so the database can use these functions. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
I have attempted setting this in c# from the app in two different ways, but both have failed.

```
 public void EnableCLR(string ConnectionString)
    {
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                con.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Error: Unable to find stored procedure "sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1"
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I tried this

```
 public void EnableCLR(string ConnectionString)
    {
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_configure", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                con.Open();

                SqlParameter clrParam = new SqlParameter();

                clrParam.ParameterName = "clr enabled";

                clrParam.Value = 1;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(clrParam);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Error: @clr enabled is not a parameter for procedure sp_configure.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that you are setting `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure`. You don't need that. The default type of `Text` is fine for this purpose. If you use the `StoredProcedure` type, then you can only specify the proc name as the `CommandText`, which you did do correctly, but then you need to set the parameter name(s) correctly. Here you used the parameter value as the name. The param names for `sp_configure` are `configname` and `configvalue` (don't need `@` on param names when doing `StoredProcedure` type). See the `sp_configure` doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you installing LocalDB? I assume you are attaching the MDF file via the Connection String, hence unable to execute these statements in a SQL script.

Assuming there is also no `SQLCMD.EXE` to run a query with, you should be able to create a separate Console App that the installer can run after installing LocalDB. That Console App can run SQL statements via `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Those SQL statements can either be hard-coded (harder to change) or it can get the configuration SQL from the app.exe.Config file.

Something along the lines of:

```cs
SqlConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection(@"(localdb)\InstanceName");
SqlCommand _Command = null;

try
{
  _Command = _Connection.CreateCommand();
  _Connection.Open();

  _Command.CommandText = "EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;";
  _Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

  _Command.CommandText = "RECONFIGURE;";
  _Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally
{
  if (_Command != null)
  {
    _Command.Dispose();
  }
  _Connection.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Yes I am attaching via the connection string with `AttachDBFilename`. I have started testing the SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() for this, but cannot figure out how to set the parameters for sp_configure. Can you provide an example that sets the 'clr enabled' option to 1? I have tried to do this in a few ways (will update my question with failed attempts) but have not had any success.

Comment: Works like a charm : ) Thank you for the guidance. Now I can finally deploy!

Comment: Aside note, but why you're using try/finally instead of using?

Comment: @Naomi Mostly because I typically do more custom stuff in the `catch` and `finally` so it is a force of habit. But the `using` construct is really just a macro for the `csc.exe` C# compiler that translates into the exact try / finally structure that I used in this answer, but with less ability to do the custom stuff. Of course, you can always add your own stuff around the `using`, but then you have various levels of scope that are sometimes beneficial, but not in the stuff that I am usually doing. Does that make sense?

Comment: @srutzky _C# compiler that translates into the exact try / finally structure that I used in this answer_ That's not completely right -- this code will leak connection if CreateCommand fails for some reason, while properly nested `using` would not.

Comment: @AndreyShchekin Thanks for pointing that out. Is it possible for `CreateCommand` to fail? And if so, the update I just made to the code would fix that issue, correct?

Comment: @srutzky I am not sure if it can fail -- probably not directly, but I prefer not to rely on things not throwing (and `using` does too). Your new change will throw `NullReferenceException` in `finally` if `CreateCommand()` fails (and it will never dispose the connection if that happens).

Comment: @AndreyShchekin Good catch (again). Thanks. Serves me right for doing that change hastily. I have updated (again), and the current structure mirrors what I typically use.